# heroku : Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, heroku

I don't know much about vue front end but I am hosting it on Heroku it looks easy in documentation and videos but I keep getting this error no matter what I do.

When I push my code on Heroku it gives me this error.

```
Enumerating objects: 95, done.
Counting objects: 100% (95/95), done.  
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
Writing objects: 100% (95/95), 922.85 KiB | 5.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 95 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0       
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.16.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.16.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.11.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:
remote:        > cashflow@0.1.0 postinstall
remote:        > npm run build
remote:
remote:
remote:        > cashflow@0.1.0 build
remote:        > vue-cli-service build
remote:
remote:        All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
remote:        Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.
remote:
remote:
remote:        -  Building for production...
remote:         ERROR  Failed to compile with 10 errors6:33:06 AM
remote:        
remote:         error  
remote:        
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/signup.04385344.js.map
remote:        
remote:         error  
remote:        
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/login.8bbc6e49.js.map
remote:        
remote:         error  
remote:        
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/dashboard.cb36601d.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/119.cc0d4e84.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/206.076964cc.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/chunk-vendors.c45faf35.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/218.16810e2b.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/862.c30a7c87.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/489.c2352728.js.map
remote:
remote:         error
remote:
remote:        Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename js/939.3bc5670c.js.map
remote:
remote:         ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
remote:        Error: Build failed with errors.
remote:            at /tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:207:23
remote:            at /tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:148:8
remote:            at /tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
remote:            at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
remote:            at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)    
remote:            at Cache.shutdown (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
remote:            at /tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1225:15
remote:            at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
remote:            at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)    
remote:            at Compiler.close (/tmp/build_db7c88fd/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1218:23)
remote:        npm ERR! code 1
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_db7c88fd
remote:        npm ERR! command failed
remote:        npm ERR! command sh -c npm run build
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.mj21d/_logs/2022-08-06T06_32_22_878Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to crunch-reporting.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/crunch-reporting.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/crunch-reporting.git'
```

I tried a lot of things like defining node version.
I tried using buildpacks on heroku.
I tried changing server.js file .

NO luck

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const serveStatic = require("serve-static")
const path = require('path');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port : " + port)
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "cashflow",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.15.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```